# Cannot read properties of undefined in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am working on my first Chrome extension to popup an alert. On my background.js I get the following message when I add my files Chrome extentions: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'onAlarm').

```js
'use strict';

function setAlarm() {
    let minutes = parseFloat($("#time").val())
    chrome.alarms.create('reminderAlarm', {
        periodInMinutes: minutes
    })
    window.close()
}

$("#submit").click(setAlarm)
```

Any idea how to fix it? I attach an image of the error and code.

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPf24.png)

Comment: You need to add `"alarms"` to `"permissions"` in your manifest.json. Also make sure you don't load it in content scripts.

Answer (score 1):

the value of the variable your function is trying to read is "undefined". in other words value is not assigned to the variable before it was read.
to debug:
`console.log("whatever is undefined")` then find the reason.

it is difficult to spot problem without seeing the code.

add to manifest.json

```
"permissions":["alarms"],
```

Comment: wOxxOm
 said it right. you have to add `permissions`